# Twig, encapsulation of a block with html and multiple extends files

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to encapsulate a **block Twig** with html and not have to rewrite this html code to each call of this block.

Here is a sample code that illustrates my problem.

File 1 :

```
#base.html.twig
<div id="content">
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

File 2 :

```
#layout.html.twig
{% extends 'file1' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         % block subHeader %}
            {% block contextualMenu %}
            {% endblock contextualMenu %} 
        {% endblock subHeader %}               
    </div>
</div> 
{% endblock body %}
```

File 3 :

```
#view.html.twig
{% extends 'file2' %}
{% block body %}
    {% block subHeader %} 
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a 
            diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac 
            quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. 
            Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue.
        </p> 

        {% block contextualMenu %}
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="{{ path('collection_new') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">New</a>              
            </div>
        {% endblock contextualMenu %} 
    {% endblock subHeader %}
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: What's your problem? Do you mean you have section in HTML which might be used in many other pages and you want to use that block in other pages?

Comment: No, my problem is when I call the "subHeader" block in the file 3, they don't display the html present in file 2.

Comment: Did you extend the parent one in child one? I mean did you extend File2 in File3?

Comment: Yes I extends them, i go add this part on the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other solution more simple is next :

File1 :

```
#base.html.twig
<div id="content">
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

File2 :

```
#layout.html.twig
{% extends 'file1' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         {% block subHeader %}
            {% block contextualMenu %}
            {% endblock contextualMenu %} 
        {% endblock subHeader %}               
    </div>
</div> 
{% endblock body %}
```

File3 :

```
#view.html.twig
{% extends 'file2' %}
{% block body %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock body %}

{% block subHeader %}
    <!-- your code -->
    {% block contextualMenu %}
        <!-- your code -->
    {% endblock contextualMenu %} 
{% endblock subHeader %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I found in the documentation for twig files [EXTENDS](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) , it seems the issue is in the nested twig files in the child one that you don't need to define them as nested, too.

```
{% extends 'BundleName:Path:file2.twig' %}
{% block subHeader %} 
    {{ parent() }}
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a 
        diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac 
        quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. 
        Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue.
    </p> 
{% endblock %}
{% block contextualMenu %}
    {{ parent() }}
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="{{ path('collection_new') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">New</a>              
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the file 2 should be:

```
{% extends 'BundleName:Path:file1.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        {% block subHeader %}
            {% block contextualMenu %}
            {% endblock %}
        {% endblock subHeader %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It's ok for the extending way, the name file1, file2 ... are just for the example. But in my code I respect the bundleName:Path:twigFileName syntax.

The second option, thx, I corrects that. but I still have the same problem. The html code who encapsulates the blocks in file2 don't display.

Comment: Can I ask what do you render in your controller?

Comment: My controller render the file3. it's ok about that. My question is why the html present in file2 who encapsulates the blocks are not display.

Comment: That's weird; I guess it's because of the nested twig files; I updated my solution hopefully that help you. I also suggest to put some text in File2 and in your controller render that one and see if it's presented

Comment: You can also test your twig files by this command `php app/console twig:lint` and check the syntax from [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#syntax-checking]

Comment: Thanks for the command line. All it's ok for the syntax. I think i anderstand the problem. The content of Body block is override. The solution could be to defined a condition into the subHeader.

Comment: Though plz dump your answer I be get it and vote for it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, but it is specific to a given situation. I explain :
I put a condition to wrap the html code of file2. For example, i do this :

File1 :

```
#base.html.twig
<div id="content">
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

File2 (with conditions) :

```
    #layout.html.twig
    {% extends 'file1' %}
    {% block body %}
        {% if bundle == 'AdminBundle'%}
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    {% block subHeader %}
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a 
                            diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac 
                            quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. 
                            Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue.
                        </p> 
                       {% if bundle == 'AdminBundle'%}
                           <div class="btn-group">
                               {% if currentRoute == 'collection' %}
                                   <a href="{{ path('collection_new') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> New
                                   </a>    
                               {% endif %}  
                               {% if currentRoute == 'image' %}
                                   <a href="{{ path('image_new') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> New
                                   </a>    
                               {% endif %}  
                           </div> 
                       {% endif %}
                   {% endblock subHeader %}               
               </div>
           </div> 
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock body %}
```

File 3 :

```
#view.html.twig
{% extends 'file2' %}
{% block body %}
    {% block subHeader %} 
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endblock subHeader %}  
{% endblock body %}
```

With this technique, the html code of file2 isn't override.